# Define value of this in typescript callbacks

Tags: typescript, generics, this

Say I have a function `addFoo` that adds a `foo` method to a class (ignore the Class type):

```
const addFoo = (c: Class, cb: () => any) => c.prototype.foo = cb;
```

It could be used as so:

```
class A {
   num: number;
}

addFoo(A, () => console.log(this.num))
```

However, typescript has no idea that `this` is an instance of `A` so it errors.
How do I provide that info to the compiler?

I was thinking something like this but I couldn't find anything online:

```
const addFoo<C extends Class>(c: C, cb: (this: InstanceType<C>, ...any) => any){}
```

It is worth mentioning that:

```
A.prototype.foo = function(){}
```

Works, but I can not use it in this case

Comment: I can't even get your addFoo function to compile: `Property 'prototype' does not exist on type 'Class'.`

Comment: Is your problem that typescript complains or that in the arrow function gets the scoped "this" instead of instance of A? Try replacing the arrow function with "function" like this `addFoo(A, function () { console.log(this.num); });` That didn't give me any errors but it also does not give the actual type to "this" so typescript does not really know what that is. Also, I changed signature of `addFoo` method: `function addFoo<T>(c: new () => T, cb: () => any) { c.prototype.foo = cb; }`

Comment: The Class type was as follows: `type Class = {new(...args: any[]): any, prototype: any}`

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it uses `addFoo(A, function () { console.log(this.num) })` instead of `addFoo(A, () => console.log(this.num))`; [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) do not have their own `this` context and cannot be used as methods, so your current example breaks in JavaScript at runtime.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAj7PW) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, please let me know what's missing.

Comment: Yea that worked thank you so much